# PhoneGap on Eclipses stays on Cordova splash Screen

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I've followed the instructions from a [youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVjCMXQGS_w) on how to set up phonegap.  but everytime I run the application, the
app just stays on the spash creen intro of the cordova robot image. The actual application
doesn't run.  Any ideas why this is happening?

P.S I downloaded eclipse from the google website with the sdk already ready and set up. I also used the android example from the latest phonegap release as of this date.

I first downloaded the phonegap zip from the phonegap website and then extracted the files.
I then created a new project from an existing source in eclipse and added the path where the cordova phonegap android example was in. I than click run as > android application  and this is where the splash screens shows like its about to work but the splash screen never goes away.

Best Regards,
KD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps because I had other problems with phonegap.
After downloading cordova 2.6.0 I've tried to do a new project following the getting started guide directions.
It didn't work.
Then I took the getting started guide directions for version 1.9.0 (you can select this on the top right of the getting started with android webpage, and it worked.
The difference is that in version 1.9.0 you have to do all the setup manually instead of using the create script they provide.
It is a pain in the butt, but it works.

Daniel

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will try that tonight. =)